# Which type of API key for Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master

It says the following in the example:

```
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");

  $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
  $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
  $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

  foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
  }
```

But when I go to get my api credentials there are SO MANY different credentials I can create. Which one is it for `YOUR_APP_KEY`?

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

A little confused as to why they need so many different keys.

Comment: Using the api client from app engine?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Google's credential wizard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/wizard?project=_). It's under the "Help me choose" option when creating a new credential. You'll likely want to use a service account since you're accessing data on behalf of your application (rather than an end-user). See [this documentation for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests).